# How can I get the url of the previous page when triggering the popstate event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, popstate

Here's a simple example of `pushState` and `popstate` event:

```
<button id="example_btn">Click me</button>

<script>
$("#example_btn").click(function(){
            history.pushState( 
                {
                    'url' : "example.htm"
                }, null, "example.htm");
});
$(window).bind('popstate', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.state) {
        console.log(event.originalEvent.state.url);
    }
});
</script>
```

When triggering the `popstate` event, it shows the url of the current page.

My question is:

How can I get the url of the **previous** page when triggering the `popstate` event in this case?
P.S. I have tried `document.referrer` but it didn't show anything.

Answer (score 4):

Please try keeping the previousUrl in a variable and listening to it.

```
<button id="example_btn">Click me</button>

<script>
var previousUrl = null;
$("#example_btn").on('click', function(){
           previousUrl = location.href;
             history.pushState( 
                {
                    'url' : "example.htm"
                }, null, "example.htm");
});
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
   console.log('Previous url was : ', previousUrl); 
};
</script>
```

Comment: And what if the user navigates multiple states back in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED & TESTED & WORKING**

---

## Extended History Object

This is my source you can see full resource from https://gist.github.com/HasanDelibas/12050fc59d675181ea973d21f882081a

---

This library contains:

- history.states -> get state list
- history.stateIndex -> current state index
- "historyChange" event  -> detect history change (from,to,side="back"|"forward")
- **Important!** `state` must be object at `history.pushState( **state**, ...)`

```
(function(){
  let stateSymbol = "__state__index__";
  history.stateIndex =-1;
  history.states=[];
  let pushState = history.pushState;
  function add(data,title,url){
    if(data==null) data={};
    if(typeof data!="object") data={data:data};
    data[stateSymbol] = (history.stateIndex+1);
    history.states.splice(history.stateIndex+1,0,[data,title,url])
    history.states.splice(history.stateIndex+2)
    history.stateIndex++;
  }
  history.pushState =function(data,title,url=null){
    add(data,title,url);
    pushState.bind(history)(data,title,url);
  }
  addEventListener("popstate",function(e){
    var eventObject= {};
    var newStateIndex =  e.state!=null ? e.state[stateSymbol] : -1;
    eventObject.from = history.states[history.stateIndex];
    eventObject.to   = newStateIndex>-1 ? history.states[newStateIndex] : null;
    eventObject.side = history.stateIndex>newStateIndex ? "back" : "forward"; 
    if( newStateIndex > -1 && !(newStateIndex in history.states) ){
      add(history.state,"",window.location.href);
    }
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("historyChange", {detail: eventObject} ))
    history.stateIndex = e.state!=null ? e.state[stateSymbol] : -1;
  });
})();
```

Now you can get all states with `history.states` object,
and detect history change with `addEventListener("popstate",function(e))`

**Using**

```
/**
  * @param e.detail.from [data,title,url]
  * @param e.detail.to   [data,title,url]
  * @param e.detail.side "back" | "forward"
  */
addEventListener("historyChange",function(e){
  var from = e.detail.from; // [ data , title , url ]
  var to   = e.detail.to;   // [ data , title , url ]
  var side = e.detail.side; // "back" | "forward"
  console.log( `You changed history. Side is ${e.detail.side}.\nFrom:${e.detail.from[2]}\nTo:${e.detail.to[2]}`)
})


history.pushState("1", "DENEME-TEST" ,"?1");
history.pushState("2", "DENEME-TEST" ,"?2");
// list of history states
console.log( history.states )
/*
[
  [ {...} ,  "DENEME-TEST" ,"?1" ]
  [ {...} ,  "DENEME-TEST" ,"?2" ]
]
*/
// get history current state index
console.log( history.stateIndex )
/*
1
*/
```

Comment: This shows the current URL, but not the URL before the popstate.

Comment: The good idea here is to extend the history object to be able to explore all back and forward states. The old URL is simply the URL of the previous state.